# Using Tensorflow on GPU interrupts the kernel and yields error: "...TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2"

Tags: gpu, tensorflow

Real noob here - trying to build a CNN using tensorflow operating on the GPU but I am struggling (tested it on the CPU and the code runs fine). When I run the code on the GPU

```
device_name = "GPU:0"
with tf.device(device_name):
    # Code here
```

things get started but after a few seconds then I get an error with the following title (this is not just a notice - it actually stops the code from continuing to run):

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
```

and the following details (only included the first few lines since it is long and repetitive)

```
2017 11:37:20.918191: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2017 11:37:21.959053: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1030] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.62
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 4.00GiB freeMemory: 3.29GiB
2017 11:37:21.959079: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) ‑> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2017 11:37:22.119554: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\direct_session.cc:299] Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 ‑> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1
```

I am pleased it found the device - the important bit seems to be:

```
Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
```

I have tried to ignore the warning using

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
import tensorflow as tf
```

but that does not change anything.

I am still learning the basics so any and all guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 different things going on here. Have you tried not specifying the device name? TensorFlow will automatically use all GPUs it has access to.

The AVX issues are because you probably installed TensorFlow using pip, but if you were to compile it using bazel, those warnings would go away.

Without seeing the ‘repetitive’ stack trace, it becomes difficult to know exactly what is going on.